# Is there a way to cancel gevent.spawn_later()?

Tags: python, gevent

If you call gevent.spawn_later(), is there a way to cancel this scheduled function before it occurs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use `kill()` method.

```
g = gevent.spawn_later(5, function)
g.kill()
```